# Error while passing parameters to RandomForest

Tags: compiler-errors, random-forest

I am trying to fit a random forest model. The code compiles if I dont use the **criterion** parameter. However it returns the following error on using it.

*criterion = CRITERIA_REG[self.criterion](self.n_outputs_,
KeyError: 'entropy'*

My attempt is this :

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
clf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100,criterion="entropy",max_features='log2',bootstrap=False,random_state=1)
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Apparently "gini" and "entropy" are no longer available. Only "mae" and "mse" are available. Can anyone one suggest how I can use "entropy"(i.e, information gain) instead ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `RandomForestRegressor`, that is why it accepts only *mae* and *mse*.
Instead, use `RandomForestClassifier`:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,criterion="entropy",max_features='log2',bootstrap=False,random_state=1)
```